# Inserting data frames to teradata by using teradatasql package

Tags: python, sql, teradata

I am using teradatasql package which native solution of Teradata as a connector between python and Teradata to load data from DB. However, I want to insert data frames I created in python back to DB. Is it possible to write data frames to the database by using teradatasql package?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy provides the linkage between pandas dataframes and a SQL database.

Typically, you would use the pandas dataframe `to_sql` method to insert the contents of a dataframe into a table in the database:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

We offer a SQLAlchemy dialect for the Teradata SQL Driver for Python:

https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy/

You can install it with: `pip install teradatasqlalchemy`